# how to check when the session was set

Tags: php, session

hello i would like to know at what time any particular session was set or started ?? is this possible by php

i know session set or not can be checked by

```
if(isset($_SESSION['name'])){
 /////////////
}
```

but here i want when the sessoin was started so that

```
if($_SESSION['name'] // started on date is greater then last 5 minutes
  ){
 // do this

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you start the session you could save when it was started in the sesson.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['startDate'] = date();
```

The code will change on how you want to store the date but that the crux of it. If you want to know when you set exactly $session['name'] you could use an array to store the name data with the date.